# fetching multiple elements in js and displaying them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to js/react api calls and am trying to use 2 apis one to fetch a random movie

1. https://k2maan-moviehut.herokuapp.com/api/random

and the second to get movie

2. http://www.omdbapi.com/

where the **t** paramter in second is movie name,  and here is my code

in my main component

```js
const getMovies = async () => {
        let movies = await fetchMovies();
        console.log(movies);
        return movies;
    }

const movies = getMovies();
```

and i call these functions from another file

```js
const getMovie = async () => {
    const omdpURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=xxxxxx&t=";
    let moviename = (await (await fetch("https://k2maan-moviehut.herokuapp.com/api/random")).json()).name
    let movie = await (await fetch(omdpURL.concat(moviename))).json();
    return movie;
}

export const fetchMovies = async() => {

    let values = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        let movie = await getMovie();
        values.push(movie)
    }
return values;
}
```

the problem is that when I try to see my movies in main component it returns a {Promise fulfilled `Array(12)`} while if I logged the movies while I call `getMovies` it gives me the result I want which is the 12 movie I called  , how can I have the results I need

Comment: *async functions* **always** return a `Promise`. Use either `async/await` or the `then` callback to handle the result from the promises.

Comment: Bro, you just leaked your OMDB API key. Please edit your question and take it out for your own sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic setup to help you get started:

```js
const getMovie = async () => {

    const randomMovieURL = "https://k2maan-moviehut.herokuapp.com/api/random";
    const omdpURL        = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=apiKey&t=";

    // Fetch the first URL and get a random movie
    const result  = await fetch(randomMovieURL);
    // Get the response and parse the JSON data coming back from this response
    const movie   = await result.json();

    // Fetch the OMDB using the random movie name
    const result2 = await fetch(omdpURL + movie.name);
    // Once again, parse the JSON from the Response we got back
    const movieData = await result2.json(); 

    // Return the JSON data which contains the movie details
    return movieData;

}

const fetchMovies = async () => {

  const requests = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // Fill in the requests Array with the asynchronous operations
    requests.push(getMovie())
  }
  // Run all 12 async operations in parallel to speed things up
  const movies = await Promise.all(requests);
  // Return the results:
  return movies;
}

// fetchMovies() is async so we need to `await` for the result inside
// another async function:
async function main(){
  const movies = await fetchMovies();
  console.log(movies);
}

main();

// Alternative syntax using then():
fetchMovies().then( movies => console.log( movies ) );
```

**Updated:**

Keep in mind, that the correct way to loop over a list of async calls in parallel and get the results, is through `Promise.all`.

Using a normal `for` loop and `await` (as in your case) will result in running all 12 calls sequentially, which is much slower.

Regarding the question:

> "the problem is that when I try to see my movies in main component it return a {Promise fulfilled Array(12)} while if I logged the movies while I call getMovies it gives me the result I want which is the 12 movie I called , how can I have the results I need"

The reason why you see a `Promise fulfilled Array(12)` in the main component is that the `getMovies` function is async and thus always returns a Promise **not a normal value**.

In order to see the value, you will need to either use `await` before the function call (`const movies = await getMovies()`) or use `then` (`getMovies().then( movies => console.log(movies) )`).

This is the reason why you see the actual value in the console.log inside `getMovies`. You are using `await` before the async function `fetchMovies`.

---

**Lesson of the day**

You have just stumbled upon one of the trickiest and hardest parts of JavaScript: asynchronous programming using Promises.

Make sure to go through the following MDN resources to get a comprehensive and solid foundation of Promises:

- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: that was really helpful and u added a lot more to be learned and special  thx for the tip of barrel fetch that was another problem I noticed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you try to nest your await fetch clauses. If you do it like this it would work.

```js
  const getMovies = async () => {
      const omdpURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=myApiKey&t=";
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://k2maan-moviehut.herokuapp.com/api/random"
      );
      var data = await res.json();
      const movie = await fetch(omdpURL + data.name);
      var moviedata = await movie.json();
      console.log(moviedata);
    };

    getMovies();
```

Comment: I tried a lot of await calls cause I was trying to get the result I want I forgot to clean them sorry about that it made the code pretty unreadable , but the problem is that the return value was not what I expected which is the values not a promise , your code is a lot more readable than mine thx